# ERROR "Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data"

Tags: javascript, json, post, fetch

Tengo un `post` en el que **no me devuelve nada**, pero si quito la parte de la respuesta me da error. Si dejo la parte de la respuesta me da el error

> "Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of
> data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data"

¿Hay algo para poder poner en vez del `return response.json()` para cuando no hay respuesta? ¿o es mejor que me devuelva un `true` o cualquier cosa el metodo?

```
const uploadFiles = () => {
  uploadModalRef.current.style.display = 'block';
  uploadRef.current.innerHTML = `${t("lectorfacturas.subiendo")} ${nFiles} ${t("lectorfacturas.archivos")}<br>${t("lectorfacturas.segundoplano")}`;
  let progress = 0
  updateseeList(false)

  for (let i = 0; i < validFiles.length; i++) {
    // console.log(i)
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', validFiles[i]);
    formData.append('key', 'add your API key here');

    fetch('url', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        // 'Accept': 'application/file',
        // 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${UserService.getToken()}`
      },
      body: formData
    }).then((response) => {
      console.log(response.status)
      if (response.status == 200 || response.status == 204) {
        console.log(response)
        progressRef.current.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
        progress += porcentaje
        progressRef.current.style.width = `${progress}%`;
      } else {
        // If error, display a message on the upload modal
        uploadRef.current.innerHTML = `<span class="error">${t("lectorfacturas.errorcarga")}</span>`;
        //                 // set progress bar background color to red
        progressRef.current.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
        progress += porcentaje
        progressRef.current.style.width = `${progress}%`;
      }

      return response.json();
    })
      .then(() => {
      // If error, display a message on the upload modal
      uploadRef.current.innerHTML = `<span class="error">${t("lectorfacturas.errorcarga")}</span>`;
      //                 // set progress bar background color to red
      progressRef.current.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
      progress += porcentaje
      progressRef.current.style.width = `${progress}%`;
    })

    // console.log(porcentaje)
    // console.log(progress)

  }
}
```

El problema está en el `return response.json()`. ¿Hay algo para poner en el `return` cuando no devuelve nada?

Comment: O sea, ¿si quitas el `return response.json()`te da un error?  ¿cual?  El error actual es porque [intentas parsear el response](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/json) al pasarle el método `json()`, y al no contener nada da el error supongo.

Comment: si quito el return response.json() se me va al catch directamente y ejecuta esa parte de codigo. Si el error es por eso, porque no contiene nada..  algo para indicar que el return response esta vacio?

Comment: No tengo la respuesta canónica, pero como puedes retornar response.json(), response.text(), response.blob(), response.arrayBuffer() y response.formData(). Esto me indica, que la verdad, puedes retornar cualquier cosa. Así que yo no veo problema en retornar true o false. Yo en tu lugar retornaría response.status == 200 || response.status == 204. Luego en la otra función haría los cambios de estilos

Comment: o return response.ok

Comment: he probado y si no pongo una funcion "response. loquesea()", me va al catch directamente

Comment: ay si, lo siento, que cambie el catch por el segundo then, me refiero al segundo then

Comment: el return lo necesito. Pero necesito que en vez de response.json sea otra cosa que de valido la respuesta vacia

Comment: me he confundido, perdona, el return no te saca del ciclo, sino que envia eso al siguiente then

Comment: sin el return se me va directamente al segundo then

Comment: Cuéntanos un poco mejor que pretendes con el segundo `then()`... ¿cuando quieres que actue y cuando no?  Lo digo porque en el segundo `then()` no estás recogiendo nada del primero al no ponerle una variable tipo `then(retorno_del_primer_then)` para luego poner un condicional en el segundo que te discrimine si quieres o no quieres sobreescribir esas variables en plan `if(retorno_del_primer_then == true) { // aqui sobresscribo} else { // aqui me las salto}`

Comment: No, no se va directamente al segundo `then()`, sino que en el segundo `then()` estás sobreescribiendo las mismas variables que en el primero

Comment: Y tampoco tengo tan claro que necesites dos `then()` para solucionar un problema de condicionales anidados que puedes resolver en uno solo seguramente

Comment: Esto es lo que digo que podrías hacer: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZH0V.png

Comment: El principal problema que veo es que tu código no es estándar en varios sentidos: 1. ¿Por qué lanzas el `fetch` dentro de un bucle? Es mejor recopilar todo lo que debas recopilar y luego pasar esos datos al `fetch`. 2. ¿Por qué tienes un `return` dentro del `fetch`? Si vas a obrar de ese modo, deberías meter el `fetch` dentro de un `async function`. Aunque esto no hace falta, si organizas mejor el código, tomando en cuenta lo que te dije en (1), no necesitarás meter un `return` dentro del `fetch` ...

Comment: ... Sea como sea, revisa por favor [la documentación sobre `fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) analizando minuciosamente los bloques de código que hay en ella, observa cómo se consume la respuesta, según el tipo de contexto. En cuanto al error en sí mismo, suele ocurrir cuando esperas un JSON y el servidor te devuelve un JSON no válido. Esto suele ocurrir porque no se tiene cuidado con las salidas desde el servidor. Es un error menor, que podrás resolver fácilmente en el futuro, para mi lo peor es tu forma de usar `fetch`.

Answer (score 1):

Cuando tienes una respuesta en formato JSON, `response.json()` es el equivalente a hacer `JSON.parse(textoJson)`. Si la respuesta del servidor es texto pero no es JSON (por ejemplo, se devuelve el texto "ok"), puedes usar `response.text()`. O puedes sólo comprobar que la respuesta es un HTTP Status 2XX (`if (response.ok) { ..}`)

Comment: Hasta donde vi, dentro del "then" tienes que agregar una variable, y en el ultimo no lo estas haciendo
Probaste reemplazar el return response.json() por 
response.json()?
y en el siguiente then, seria
.then((data) =>